# Sed - print lines from regex to (regex or eof)

Tags: sed

How to make `sed` print lines from the one matching regex (inclusive) to the one matching other regex (inclusive), but with the added condition - the closing regex might not be present at all, in which case everything till EOF should be printed?

Example1 (assuming `^START.*` and `^END.*` as the delimiting regexes):

```
cruft1
cruft2
START print this
print this
print this
END print this too
cruft
```

Example2:

```
cruft1
cruft2
START print this
print this
print this
- file ends here
```

Subquestion: print only the first such occurence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match all lines from ^START to ^END

```
 sed -n '/^START/,/^END/p' <file>
```

Print first occurence

```
 sed -n '/^START/,/^END/ {p;q;}' <file>
```

Comment: First one works for me too also until EOF, but not the second one. It will execute the `q` at the START. You will need a second condition, like: `sed -n '/^START/,/^END/ {p; /^END/ q;}' <file>`

Comment: What OS are you guys using?

Comment: Ok, I made a silly mistake while checking this out. This works (with the caveat spotted by Birei.) Thanks!